# SQL запрос в зависимости от GET параметра

Tags: php, sql, get

Как правильно сформировать SQL запрос, в зависимости от наличия или отсутствия GET параметра? На странице есть переключатели, типо показать всё (get параметр отсутствует) и показать определенный тип контента. Я это сделал следующим образом, но думаю что это не правильно. Как лучше сделать?

```
function getPopularPosts($mysqli){
    $where = isset($_GET['type']) ? "WHERE tc.id = {$_GET['type']}" : "";
    $sql= "
        SELECT
        p.id,
        date_create,
        title,
        text_content,
        quote_author,
        image_url,
        video_url,
        link,
        avatar_url,
        view_number,
        u.login,
        tc.name_icon as post_type
        FROM posts p
        JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
        JOIN type_contents tc ON p.type_id = tc.id
        {$where}
        ORDER BY view_number DESC LIMIT 6;
    ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $result = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: С условием норм. А вот то, что не используются плейсхолдеры - плохо

Comment: Про плейсхолдеры немного не понял, в интерфейсе mysqli есть подготовленные запросы (это не не то же самое что плейсхолдеры?). Если использовать подготовленные запросы, то нужно указывать "WHERE id = ?" а потом биндить значение. Вопрос тогда такой, что биндить, если нет GET параметра? По сути, когда его нет, мне where в запросе и не нужен.

Comment: Ну если его нет - значит и плейсхолдер не нужен.

Comment: можно и без плейсхолдера, но значение выбирается по твоему белому списку значений.